# Cartoon in which some kids can transform into warriors and fight against evil forces

Tags: story-identification, cartoon

In this cartoon, our heroes enter in a different world separately through a train. They all have a scanner-like object which they use to scan and find their avatars.

The main kid got an avatar which is red in colour, and which can use the element of fire. He also got the second stage of his avatar, which is in another man's body and isn't able to control it. That man got that second form in a temple (as I remember it), so our heroes defeated him and the main kid takes that avatar into his gadget, which looks like a mobile and now able to control the second avatar too. Later in the story he is able to fuse both of his characters and becomes more powerful.

The second main kid got his avatar in a dark area whilst protecting the first kid, then he says that the power of light is found in darkness. His avatar uses a lightsaber-like sword like in Star Wars (it emits light). He also got the second form of his avatar, which looks like dog or wolf and white in colour.

They were total of 4-5 children, each one with their own avatar.

Comment: Just to check, is it an American/European cartoon, or may it possibly be a Japanese one (i.e. anime)? You might also want to check whether [this guidelines on story-ID](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/98028) jog some memories you could [edit] in :)

Comment: I'd swear we had one similar to this recently. Three different people were looking for it in success, had a name ending in an X like Kaotix or Chantix.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots You might be thinking of _Chaotic_, but while there is a fire warrior of sorts he really doesn't look like a dog. Not an Earth breed at least.

Comment: @Jenayah: Looking through the history, I think I was thinking of *Gormiti: the Lords of Nature Return!* as the one that was asked about repeatedly, but it's a different cartoon that I remember being cited recently, with a fire guy. that said, *Chaotic* does match on a few points...

Comment: @AdityaKumar: When you say they "enter in a different world separately through a train", do you mean they all of their own train? Or are you just saying it's a separate world. Do you remember anything about the first character's avatar's second form other than it being humanoid?

Comment: May I also repeat my question? Is it an American/European cartoon, or may it possibly be a Japanese one (i.e. anime)? did you watch it in English? :)

Comment: @FuzzyBoots they all enter in a same world but with different trains. And I don't remember much about their avatars except that all of their avatar's uses different elements like main kid's avatar uses fire. Second kid's avatar got the power of light. And I don't remember the power of other kids avatars.

Comment: @Jenayah I am from India and I watched this cartoon at young age. On that time I don't know the difference between American and Japanese cartoon. All I know that I am watching a cartoon. And for language I watched it in Hindi.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots And come to think of it I think their trains can talk too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is it Digimon Frontier?

[image]

Synopsis:
After prompted to do so by unusual phone messages, five children go to a subway station and take a train to the Digital World. There, they meet Bokomon and Neemon, who act as their guides and tell the children that the Digital World is being destroyed, and the children must fight the evil Cherubimon and his Legendary Warrior servants in order to save the world.

The five DigiDestined have D-Tectors which alow them to turn into Human Spirits and Beast Spirits with different abilities.

More Information found here: 
https://digimon.fandom.com/wiki/Digimon_Frontier

Comment: Thanks man for finding it out but I found it on my own by coincidence. But seeing the date when you answered it, you got it before me but I forgot about this site so I couldn't saw your answer. But thanks for your effort and thanks to others too who engages in this post. Looking this post after 4 years sure bring some memories. I just wish that I could talk to you Jenayah, fuzzyboots, mehall100. I hope you all are OK, we all got hit by pandemic and I can only hope that no one of you lost your life.